# Import XML (CDATA)

Tags: mysql, xml, cdata

Good afternoon !

I have researching in all web, and i haven´t found anything about it. That´s weird, maybe it´s a personal problem. Because anyone has problem like me.

So, i made a simple command in mysql to make that job

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 
    'person.xml'
INTO TABLE 
    person
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY 
    '<person>'
```

The file person.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<list>
  <person>
      <field name="person_id">5</field>
      <field name="fname"><![CDATA[Ronström]]></field>
      <field name="lname">Ulin</field>
  </person>
  <person>
      <field name="person_id">6</field>
      <field name="fname"><![CDATA[Mikael]]></field>
      <field name="lname">Sköld</field>
  </person>
</list>
```

The INSERT is done without problems, the point is that not make the insert the values inside of the tag CDATA, it´s returning NULL. There is some way to strip that tag, to return only values ?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of (also unanswered) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107639/problems-with-mysql-load-xml-infile and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882983/importing-xml-to-mysql-errors

Comment: Charlie... there is no solution in the both topics... I need some solution to that simple detail. By the way, thanks to help me.

Comment: I know you'd like a solution... I did some searching but haven't come across this before. :-/

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get this to work using `LOAD XML INFILE` either - it appears to eat the CDATA contents.

I did get it working using regular old `LOAD DATA INFILE` though. Given your example XML file and this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
  `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `fname` text,
  `lname` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

running this will import the data from the file into the table:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 
    '/tmp/person.xml'
INTO TABLE 
    people
CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
LINES STARTING BY '<person>' TERMINATED BY '</person>'
(@person)
SET
  person_id = ExtractValue(@person, '//field[@name="person_id"]'),
  fname     = ExtractValue(@person, '//field[@name="fname"]'),
  lname     = ExtractValue(@person, '//field[@name="lname"]')
;
```

This works by telling LOAD DATA INFILE that each `<person>...</person>` is a logical 'line', which it stores in the local variable `@person`. We then pass this to the [ExtractValue()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue) function as an XML fragment, select the values from it that we want using the appropriate XPath expression and store the result in the appropriate column.

Answer (score 0):

Ronaldo,
This may or may not pertain to your question (and you probably have already found a solution) but for anyone else:

If you're using php to load the xml file:

You need to load the xml file with the LIBXML_NOCDATA flag set.  That will pull it in properly.

So if you had before:
`$xml = simplexml_load_file('some/file/path.xml');`

You want this:

`$xml = simplexml_load_file('some/file/path.xml',null,LIBXML_NOCDATA);`